# Make into child of a object in unity 3d in c#

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, transform, parent-child

My code is here

```
GameObject mainpumkinclone = (GameObject)Instantiate(pumkin, 
floorPosition + new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
mainpumkinclone.transform.parent = transform.Find("prickle" + i);
```

But mainpumkincloneis not become a child of a specific prickle.

Please help to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is tranform.Find returning anything in your case? And please provide more code.

Comment: Then you have to find out why it is null. May be your find condition needs modification.

Comment: thanks manish. i find it with gameobject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is GameObject "prickle" named like that in the Editor? Is i a number that would match that game object? For example, "prickle1" is a GameObject in the Editor scene. If the answer is yes to both of these then try this.

```
mainpumpkinclone.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("prickle" + i).transform;
```

Comment: mainpumpkinclone.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("prickle" + i).transform; is correct anwer

Comment: Good luck, I hope you make a fun game!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [Unity script reference page on `Transform`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html), that class has no function `Find`. To find an object by name, as you are trying to do, you need to use the class function `Find` of the class `GameObject`, as documented [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html). Then you assign that game object's transform (using its [`transform` property](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html)) as the parent of your other game object. Specifically, do this:

```
mainpumpkinclone.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("prickle" + i).transform
```